# Recoding a variable that is both letters and numbers in r

Tags: r, character, numeric, recode

I have a variable which is coded with both letters and numbers and I am trying to get it all into numbers. The letters are A through Z, and I would like them coded as 1 through 26. The numeric entries are 2 through 8, and I would like them coded as 27 through 33. I can't seem to find a good way of doing this.

For example, my variable looks similar to:

```
var = c('A',2,3,8,'C','W',6,'T')
```

I would want A = 1, 2 = 27, 3 = 28, 8 = 33, C = 3, W = 23, 6 = 31, and T = 20.

Basically var is A:Z and 2:8. But the numbers [2:8] need to be larger numbers than the letters. The letters need to correspond to their position in the alphabet.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output as it is not clear how the variable is coded

Comment: @akrun I added some info. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Try `match(var, c(LETTERS, 2:8))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match(var, c(LETTERS, 2:8))` also looks like it gives the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We could do this using

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- setNames(as.character(27:33), 2:8)[var]
v2 <- setNames(as.character(1:26), LETTERS)[var]

as.vector(coalesce(v1, v2))
```